# Querying the retention rate on multiple days with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a simple data model that consists of a `user` table and a `check_in` table with a `date` field, I want to calculate the retention date of my users. So for example, for all users with one or more check ins, I want the percentage of users who did a check in on their 2nd day, on their 3rd day and so on.

My SQL skills are pretty basic as it's not a tool that I use that often in my day-to-day work, and I know that this is beyond the types of queries I am used to. I've been looking into pivot tables to achieve this but I am unsure if this is the correct path.

Edit:

The user table does not have a registration date. One can assume it only contains the ID for this example.

Here is some sample data for the `check_in` table:

```
|   user_id   |         date        |
=====================================
| 1           | 2020-09-02 13:00:00 |   
-------------------------------------
| 4           | 2020-09-04 12:00:00 |
-------------------------------------
| 1           | 2020-09-04 13:00:00 |
-------------------------------------
| 4           | 2020-09-04 11:00:00 |
-------------------------------------
|                ...                |
-------------------------------------
```

And the expected output of the query would be something like this:

```
| day_0 | day_1 | day_2 | day_3 |
=================================
| 70%   | 67 %  | 44%   | 32%   |
---------------------------------
```

Please note that I've used random numbers for this output just to illustrate the format.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, no images.)  [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh I believe the question is already pretty descriptive, no? There's a description of the data model which is nothing beyond the classic SQL relation example followed by a description of what the query should do. I could add some sample data but that would just be a list of user ids followed by a date.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: I would also suggest making some sample data in a working example.  Maybe adapt this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/788089

Comment: You didn't specify which columns the `user` table. Does it have a registration date or something?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis it does not. Assume just an ID for this example

Comment: How could day 0 be 70%?  What is day 0 if not the earliest record in the table?

Comment: For the OP: If there are two people, one with initial date 1 Dec, the second with initial date 3 Dec. They both sign in for the first time on 3 Dec. How do you know that that is day#2 for the first person, but day#0 for the second (e.g., what table columns do you use to calculate 0 and 2 for the day number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see.  Assuming you mean days between checkins for users -- and users might have none -- then just use aggregation and window functions:

```
select sum( (ci.date = ci.min_date)::numeric ) / u.num_users as day_0,
       sum( (ci.date = ci.min_date + interval '1 day')::numeric ) / u.num_users as day_1,
       sum( (ci.date = ci.min_date + interval '2 day')::numeric ) / u.num_users as day_2
from (select u.*, count(*) over () as num_users
      from users u
     ) u left join
     (select ci.user_id, ci.date::date as date,
             min(min(date::date)) over (partition by user_id order by date) as min_date
      from checkins ci
      group by user_id, ci.date::date
     ) ci;
```

Note that this aggregates the `checkins` table by user id and date.  This ensures that there is only one row per date.